# window.find() in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I am using window.find() method to find a space and highlight the same programmatically.
     `window.find(' ');`
This is acting very differently in Chrome compared to firefox.

In firefox it finds and highlights the character immediately after the current caret position. Where as in Chrome it finds from 0th position and always highlights the first space in the window. Any solution how we can get this working like Firefox? Or any Jquery equivalent for this so that it can work independent of browser?

Comment: It's not a standard method - it may work entirely differently, or not at all, in any given browser, and may even change between versions of the same browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery plugin. [jQuery Highlight](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html)